# Python: add 1 to each digit that is an integer

Tags: python

```
samples = list('SX00182')

def add(x):
    if type(x) == int:
        return x + 1

new_sample = map(add, samples)

result = ''.join(new_sample)
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: What to do if you have a `9`?

Comment: oooh good question, it should go to 0 I think

Comment: @Ffisegydd: well, since the OP first turned the whole string into a list of individual characters, lets assume `SX11293`, as `map()` would apply `add` to each individual element of that list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are dealing with strings here, each character is still a string and `type(x)` will never be `int`. You wanted [`str.isdigit()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) instead.

Use a list comprehension instead:

```
new_sample = [x if not x.isdigit() else str((int(x) + 1) % 10) for x in samples]
```

Here the expression `str((int(x) + 1) % 10)` casts your character to an integer, adds 1, 'wraps round' to `0` if the result was 10, and turns the whole result into a string again.

You don't need to turn `samples` into a list even, this works on strings too:

```
>>> samples = 'SX00182'
>>> [x if not x.isdigit() else str((int(x) + 1) % 10) for x in samples]
['S', 'X', '1', '1', '2', '9', '3']
```

Complete code:

```
def increment_digits(string):
    return ''.join([x if not x.isdigit() else str((int(x) + 1) % 10) for x in string])
```

Demo:

```
>>> def increment_digits(string):
...     return ''.join([x if not x.isdigit() else str((int(x) + 1) % 10) for x in string])
... 
>>> increment_digits('SX00182')
'SX11293'
>>> increment_digits('SX11293')
'SX22304'
```

Note that even if you *could* use a `type(x) == int` test, you should never use `type()` that way. First of all, types are best tested with identity (`type(x) is int`), not equality, and you'd use `isinstance(x, int)` instead to allow for subclasses too.

Comment: I had almost the same solution, but too slow again. Only difference is that I prefered lambda (`increment = lambda x: str((int(x) + 1) % 10)` ), which makes comprehension more readable: `print ''.join(increment(char) if char.isdigit() else char for char in samples)`

Answer (score 1):

Generally in Python, "more efficient" means "do less" and "push it down so any loops are happening at a lower level - looping in C rather than in Python".

Since you only have ten, single character mappings (0:1, 1:2, etc.) then there's absolutely no need to check them to see if they are digits, convert them to integers, mathematically calculate on them, modulo the answer to keep it a single digit, build a list, add them to the list, then convert the whole thing back to a string.

Instead, replace them blindly as text, and then, push that down to a C library feature which does the work for you. String.maketrans maps the *text* characters on the left to the ones on the right, and then string.translate replaces text characters using the translation table.

```
import string
samples = "SX00182"

translation = string.maketrans('0123456789', '1234567890')

print string.translate(samples, translation)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
next_digit = {str(i):str((i+1)%10) for i in range(10)}

def incr(s):
    return ''.join(next_digit.get(ch, ch) for ch in s)

incr("SX001829")   # => 'SX112930'
```